# My vs code is over zoomed and its not coming to its original form .I have install and uninstall many time but its the same

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l1bo.png)

The image is of vs code

Comment: Try focusing the window, then pressing `Ctrl + Num 0` - Should reset your zoom to default; `Ctrl + +` and `Ctrl + -` can be used to increase and decrease zoom respectively

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>     should zoom you out.

Comment: THANKS but Its not working all keyboard short cuts I have tried  its the same.

Comment: maybe try to manually reset zoom with the reset zoom setting under View>Appearance>Reset Zoom.